# Want to create multiple JSON Object in android

Tags: android

I have to pass JSON data in web services. Like below

"customerAccount": {
"payloadType": "KEYED",
"accountType": "CHECKING",
"cardDetails": {
"dataFormat": "PLAIN_TEXT",
"cardNumber": "5454545454545454",
"expiryDate": "1221",
"cvv": "123",
"issueNumber": "01"
}
}

Kindly guide me on how can I create JSON Object.
PS: Kindly not comment for JSONArray(). I have to use JSON Object, not JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean some java json parse framework?
You can try fastjson or jackson.